# How to get Header Text from dynamically created sortable accordion?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently dynamically creating tables with accordions where I perform sortable operations in jquery to drop information from other tables. Everything works fine but here's the problem: I want to use the header text of the dynamically created accordions for my database, but I don't know how to get this information. Here's a picture of my page.

[image: dynamic header text]

Here's my html code for the created table

```
<div id="codigosAgrupadores">
    <div id="catalog">
        @foreach (CodigoAgrupadorCuentas_CE c in Model.CodigosAgrupadores)
        {
            if (unchecked(double.Parse(c.CodigoAgrupador) == (int)double.Parse(c.CodigoAgrupador)))
            {
                <h3><a href="#">@c.CodigoAgrupador  -  @c.NombreCuenta</a></h3>
                <div>
                    <div class="subcatalog">
                        @foreach (CodigoAgrupadorCuentas_CE c2 in Model.CodigosAgrupadores)
                        {
                            if (double.Parse(c2.CodigoAgrupador) > double.Parse(c.CodigoAgrupador) && double.Parse(c2.CodigoAgrupador) < (double.Parse(c.CodigoAgrupador) + 1))
                            {
                                <h4><a href="#">@c2.CodigoAgrupador  -  @c2.NombreCuenta</a></h4>
                                <div>
                                    <div class="SpecificCatalog">
                                        <ol>
                                            <li class="placeholder">Add your items here</li>
                                        </ol>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            }
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div class="GeneralCatalog">
                        <ol>
                            <li class="placeholder">Add your items here</li>
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

How could I access the header data with Jquery? Here's an example of one of my sortables with the stop function, I am able to access the droppable element information, but I want to access the header information of the accordion that contains the dropped element.

```
$(".GeneralCatalog").sortable({
    connectWith: ".SpecificCatalog, .listaCatalogosContenido", helper: "clone",
    appendTo: "body",

    stop: function (event, ui) {
        //console.log((this).sortable('toArray', { attribute: 'value' }));
        console.log(ui.item);
        console.log(ui.item.text());
    }
});
```

**EDIT:** Here's the rendered HTML of the specific part of the picture I showed.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#catalog").accordion({ collapsible: true, active: false, autoHeight: false });
        $(".subcatalog").accordion({ collapsible: true, active: false, autoHeight: false });

        $(".SpecificCatalog").sortable({
            connectWith: ".listaCatalogosContenido, .GeneralCatalog", helper: "clone",
            appendTo: "body",

            stop: function (event, ui) {
                //console.log((this).sortable('toArray', { attribute: 'value' }));
                console.log(ui.item);
                console.log(ui.item.text());
            }

        });
        $(".listaCatalogosContenido").sortable({
            connectWith: ".SpecificCatalog, .GeneralCatalog", helper: "clone",
            appendTo: "body",

            stop: function (event, ui) {
                //console.log((this).sortable('toArray', { attribute: 'value' }));
                console.log(ui.item);
                console.log(".head h3");
                console.log(ui.item.text());
            }
        });
        $(".GeneralCatalog").sortable({
            connectWith: ".SpecificCatalog, .listaCatalogosContenido", helper: "clone",
            appendTo: "body",

            stop: function (event, ui) {
                //console.log((this).sortable('toArray', { attribute: 'value' }));
                console.log(ui.item);
                console.log(ui.item.text());
            }
        });
    });
</script>



<div id="wrapper">
<h2>LigarAGrupo</h2>
<div id="content">
    <div id="ListaCodigos">
        <h2 class="ui-widget-header">CodigoAgrupador</h2>
        <div id="codigosAgrupadores">
            <div id="catalog">
                <h3><a href="#">1  -  Caja</a></h3>
                <div>
                    <div class="subcatalog">
                        <h4><a href="#">1.1  -  Caja y efectivo</a></h4>
                        <div>
                            <div class="SpecificCatalog">
                                <ol>
                                    <li class="placeholder">Add your items here</li>
                                </ol>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="GeneralCatalog">
                        <ol>
                            <li class="placeholder">Add your items here</li>
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Also, here's the html that I get from F12 -> Elements in google chrome.

[image: Elements]

Comment: it will be easier to say if you show rendered html in question. You can get it from brouser with F12 key.

Comment: I'm using google chrome, when I press F12 I just get the javascript console, not HTML. I Updated my question with what I think, is what you asked for.

Comment: f12 -> elements in chrome

Comment: I think it is done. information added to the question.

Answer (score 1):

As i understand you post here not the whole View. But i think this jquery code should alert you all values that you need.

```
$("div#catalog h3 a").each(function(item)
{
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

don't forget to place this code inside `document.ready()` function, just in case.

Comment: Is there a way to specifically get only the h3 that belongs to the accordion content where an item is dropped?

Comment: Select item, F12 -> elements -> find class that jquery put on selected element and all it to selector. :)